# Changing date-time to Month, Day, Year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I am integrating a new bootstrap template on my current Rails website. I am working on my blog and right now I have posts shown like ["10 minutes ago"](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/3732078f-f227-467c-a04b-c32cd58423bd/3adf816f6873dd50a7ed424bd1844b70). I want to change the date format like [Dec, 21, 2012 in separate lines](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/d6f79430-4cb0-490c-bf79-eefd07772f97/aca82086d38fd8032bfc12914c24829e).

The new template does this by just hardcoding the date:

```
  <div class="blog-date">
    <span class="blog-date-month">Dec</span>
    <span class="blog-date-day">21</span>
    <span class="blog-date-year">2012</span>
  </div>
```

The way I get the date is by using this:

```
time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
```

My question is how can I extract the date that the post was created in separated elements like the month, the year and the day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time_ago_in_words` will convert the Time object to a human representable and easily readable string.

In your case you don't need that. You can simply use the date/time methods on `post.created_at` to get back the year, month and day:

- `post.created_at.year`
- `post.created_at.mday`
- `post.created_at.month`

Note that these will return the results in numbers (eg 12 instead of Dec). You can use `I18n` utils to get back the abbreviated name like this:

- `I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names")[post.created_at.month]`

You can alsu use [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to convert a Time to string:

- `post.created_at.strftime('%b')`

Note however, that this won't go through Rails' I18n engine if you care about internationalization.